# ArrayAdapter - Get given resource id for list items

Tags: android, listview, resources

On extending an ArrayAdapter, i can select a constructor with resource as parameter:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
```

This resource can be used as a Layout for ListView items. But how do I get access to the given resource? I can´t find a Method like getResource or getItemLayoutResource. All I am doing for now is this.resource = resource in my constructor so I can use it later. But why should I do this if i can give the resource to the BaseAdapter over:

```
super(context, resource, objects);
```

Why do I need this: I would like to use it in my LayoutInflator on getView.
Maybe I understand this Parameter wrong. What does it exactly do on super?

Comment: Why you want to access resource?? Why don't you go with Custom Adapter?

Comment: The ArrayAdapter does everything i want.

Comment: What you wanna do with resource?? Explain

Comment: I want to have different Layouts for my ListView depending on my Code. I give the Layout to the constructor but I was missing the Method to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The super does something very similar to what you do, and the basic implementation of getView uses it.
If you just use an ArrayAdapter without extending it and give it a resource like simple_list_item_1 you'll get a basic display of your strings.

You can check the code here :
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.0mResource

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return createViewFromResource(position, convertView, parent, mResource);
}
```

where mResource is saved from the resource you provided in the constructor.

Unfortunately, it is a private member with no getter

Comment: "Unfortunately, it is a private member with no getter".
Thank you. This is what I wanted to know. I thought there would be a way to access it.